# マクロの設定による置換の速度についてです。

Tags: emeditor

お世話になっております。
例えば以下のような正規表現でない場合は記載によっては、もっと速くなりますでしょうか？
それとも正規表現指定でなくても変わらないのでしょうか？

```
batch_list = editor.filters;
batch_list.AddReplace("東京","大阪",eeFindReplaceRegExp,0);
document.selection.BatchReplace(batch_list,eeReplaceAll,eeExFindRegexOnigmo);
```

この場合は、置換は正規表現ではないのでOnigmoやBoost.Regexを指定以外の別の記載にしたほうが速くなるのでしょうか？

質問の趣旨としましては、置換の処理原理的に違うので速度が変わる負荷が変化するものなのか？まったく同じことなので変化しないのか？書き方で変化するかしないかという意味の質問になります。

少数ならいずれにしてもたいした差はないと思いますが、このようなパターンが100万個並んでいる場合などです。
よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: 以前の質問でも [コメントで指摘されていましたが](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/75344/%e3%82%a8%e3%83%87%e3%82%a3%e3%82%bf%e3%81%ae-%e7%bd%ae%e6%8f%9b-%e6%a9%9f%e8%83%bd%e3%81%a8%e5%ae%9f%e8%b3%aa%e7%9a%84%e3%81%ab%e5%90%8c%e3%81%98%e3%81%93%e3%81%a8%e3%82%92%e3%82%88%e3%82%8a%e9%80%9f%e3%81%8f%e5%87%a6%e7%90%86%e3%81%99%e3%82%8b%e6%96%b9%e6%b3%95%e3%81%af%e3%81%82%e3%82%8a%e3%81%be%e3%81%99%e3%81%a7%e3%81%97%e3%82%87%e3%81%86%e3%81%8b#comment85239_75344) 、単に "もっと速く" は抽象的すぎる気がします。

Comment: 質問の趣旨としましては、置換の処理原理的に速度が変わる負荷が変化するものなのか？まったく同じことで変化しないのか？書き方で変化するかしないかという意味の質問になります。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`eeExFindRegexBoost` か `eeExFindRegexOnigmo` を指定しなければ、既定の正規表現エンジンを使用することになります。既定の正規表現エンジンを使用する場合には、`eeExFindRegexBoost`、`eeExFindRegexOnigmo` の指定を省略しても速度には変化はありません。